# Adding multiple GroundOverlay's creates a recurring anomaly in tile positions

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

Hello fellow StackExchange members,

I am really struggling with adding  multiple GroundOverlays and/or CustomOverlays. Google Maps always shows a slight and recurring anomaly in positioning the tiles. The image below shows what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmPa4.jpg (I don't have enough reputation to show the image inline).

I used Google's example code of how to use the CustomOverlay, as shown below, and a prebuild grid.json file which houses all the tile image keys and their SW and NE bounds:

The Maps file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            *{ margin:0;padding:0;}
            html{ height: 100%;}
            body{ height: 100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
            #map-canvas{ height: 100%; }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOwFuc5S-hRJnfyYI3xL-0TJNcPjbRd2s&sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">



            // This example creates a custom overlay called USGSOverlay, containing
            // a U.S. Geological Survey (USGS) image of the relevant area on the map.

            // Set the custom overlay object's prototype to a new instance
            // of OverlayView. In effect, this will subclass the overlay class.
            // Note that we set the prototype to an instance, rather than the
            // parent class itself, because we do not wish to modify the parent class.

            var overlay;
            USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

            // Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.960515285616523328826588112860918045043945312500, 
  4.026193748674999461911738762864843010902404785156 ),
                    zoom: 13

                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas'), mapOptions );

                var grid = $.getJSON( 'grid.json', function( json ){

                    $.each( json, function( index, value )
                    {
                        var image = index + '.png';
                        var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng( value['sw'][0], value['sw'][1] );
                        var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng( value['ne'][0], value['ne'][1] );

                        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( swBound, neBound )

                        overlay = new USGSOverlay( bounds, image, map );
                        overlay.setOpacity( 50 );
                    });

                });
            }

            /** @constructor */
            function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

              // Initialize all properties.
              this.bounds_ = bounds;
              this.image_ = image;
              this.map_ = map;

              // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
              // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
              // method so we'll leave it null for now.
              this.div_ = null;

              // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
              this.setMap(map);
            }

            /**
             * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
             * added to the map.
             */
            USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div.className = 'reset';
              div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
              div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
              div.style.position = 'absolute';
              div.style.opacity = '0.6';

              // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
              var img = document.createElement('img');
              img.src = this.image_;
              img.style.width = '100%';
              img.style.height = '100%';
              img.style.position = 'absolute';
              div.appendChild(img);

              this.div_ = div;

              // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
              var panes = this.getPanes();
              panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
            };

            USGSOverlay.prototype.setOpacity = function( op )
            {
                $('div.reset').css( 'opacity', op/100 );
            }

            USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

              // We use the south-west and north-east
              // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
              // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
              var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

              // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
              // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
              // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
              var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
              var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

              // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
              var div = this.div_;
              div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
              div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
              div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
              div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
            };

            // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
            // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
            USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
              this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
              this.div_ = null;
            };

            google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initialize );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To give an idea of the contents of grid.json, here's an excerpt:

```
{
 "110-861": {
  "ne": [
   51.952818013763725, 
   3.959379207489501
  ], 
  "sw": [
   51.94812597892079, 
   3.952079437462081
  ]
 }, 
 "110-862": {
  "ne": [
   51.95741935496997, 
   3.9592327762378288
 ], 
  "sw": [
   51.95272731127462, 
   3.9519322780340236
  ]
 },
...
}
```

It consists of many keys ( like "110-862" ) which represent, after a calculation, Rijksdriehoeks Coordinates (a Dutch geospatial representation). These coordinates have been converted to WGS84 with a precision of 0.2mm. Still I get these strange distortions.

Is there anyone who has experience in using this much map tiles together?

With kind regards